What can be said about an inner product under a partial isometry?
Suppose $x, y$ are two unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $U \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 2}$ be a partial isometry in the sense that $U^T U = I_2$
What can be said about the relationship between $\langle x, y\rangle$ and $\langle U^Tx , U^T y\rangle$?
In particular is it possible to characterize the set of achievable values
$$
\{ \langle U^T x, U^T y \rangle : U^T U = I_2, U \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 2}\} ?
$$
For instance, in the case $n = 2$, this is a singleton, $\{\langle x, y \rangle\}$, but for $n > 2$, what can be said?

The product $Ux$ doesn't make sense when $U$ is an $n \times 2$ matrix and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Oops, should (obviously) be $U^T$

Given a subspace $H \leqslant \mathbb{R}^n$, let $\pi_H : \mathbb{R}^n \to H$ denote the orthogonal projection on $H$. We first show that
$$\left\{ \left< U^{\top} x, U^{\top} y \right> : U \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 2}, \, U^{\top} U = I_2 \right\} = \{ \left< \pi_H(x), \pi_H(y) \right> : H \leqslant \mathbb{R}^n, \, \dim H = 2 \}.$$
Indeed, if $U$ is any $n \times 2$ matrix satisfying $U^{\top} U = I_2$, then its image $H \leqslant \mathbb{R}^n$ is two-dimensional and
$$\left< U^{\top} x, U^{\top} y \right> = \left< \pi_H(x), \pi_H(y) \right>.$$
On the other hand, given a two-dimensional subspace $H \leqslant \mathbb{R}^n$, take $U$ such that its columns form an orthonormal basis of $H$. Then $U^{\top} U = I_2$, $H = \operatorname{Im} U$ and $\left< \pi_H(x), \pi_H(y) \right> = \left< U^{\top} x, U^{\top} y \right>$. So the sets are equal.
Now we compute the set explicitly. Since $\| x \| \cdot \| y \|$ can be factored out uniformly, we can assume that $\| x \| = \| y \| = 1$. Let $p = \frac{x+y}{2} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $q = \frac{x-y}{2} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then we have $x = p+q$, $y = p-q$ and $p \perp q$. Hence for any $H \leqslant \mathbb{R}^n$
$$\left< \pi_H(x), \pi_H(y) \right> = \left< \pi_H(p) + \pi_H(q), \pi_H(p) - \pi_H(q) \right> = \| \pi_H(p) \|^2 - \| \pi_H(q) \|^2.$$
The result clearly lies in the interval $[-\| q \|^2, \| p \|^2]$. The upper bound is realized by choosing $H$ such that $p \in H$ and $q \perp H$, which is possible because $p \perp q$ and $n > 2$. Likewise, the lower bound can be realized by taking $H$ so that $q \in H$ and $p \perp H$. By continuity, the interval $[-\| q \|^2, \| p \|^2]$ is precisely the set of possible values of $\left< \pi_H(x), \pi_H(y) \right>$, and so of $\left< U^{\top} x, U^{\top} y \right>$.
If we drop the assumption that $\| x \| = \| y \| = 1$, the final result in terms of $x$ and $y$ is
$$\left[ \frac{ \left< x, y \right> - \| x \| \| y \| }{2}, \frac{ \left< x, y \right> + \| x \| \| y \| }{2} \right].$$
